# app suddenly cannot connect to local database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

A spring mvc application using hibernate on CentOS 7 is suddenly not able to create a database connection when I restart tomcat 8. This means I cannot log into the application. The database connection was working perfectly for a long time. The only change I made recently was to follow the instructions in [this OpenVPN tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7), with the exception of using `firewalld` instead of `iptables` as in the tutorial.  I am not certain that the OpenVPN changes caused this problem, but I reversed almost all the steps in the tutorial just to check: `yum remove openvpn easy-rsa -y`, remove firewalld changes, etc) But the problem still persists.

**How can I get my app to successfully connect to the database again?**

My database connection string is:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atest?autoReconnect=true
```

The relevant message during tomcat startup is:

```
INFO  ConnectionProviderInitiator - HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
WARN  JdbcServicesImpl - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
INFO  Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
INFO  LobCreatorBuilder - HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
```

I also checked other things like confirming the password is correct, logging into the database using the shell to confirm it is working, etc.

**EDIT**

I checked the contents of /etc by doing `cd /etc` and then `ls -al` and the results included the following: `host.conf, hostname, hosts, hosts.allow, hosts.deny`.  I checked each of the files just now, and their contents do not seem to have changed since the last time I modified them, long before this problem emerged.

As per @shinjw's request, /etc/hosts contains the following, but the following has not changed since long before this problem emerged:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
abc.de.fgh.ij mydomain.com mydomain
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

Comment: Looks like a networking problem between your server hosting the tomcat 8 and your database (which is extremely odd because the database is installed in localhost).

Comment: Check your HOST files in your system32/etc

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The database and tomcat are on the same CentOS 7 box.  I dont know if one of the commands in the tutorial blocked access to the database via hibernate, but I am able to log into the same server box using the terminal and open mysql, check that the database is there, check the password, etc.

Comment: @shinjw Please see my edited edit at the end of my OP.  `/etc/hosts` has not changed.

Comment: any changes in any of your etc files??

Comment: @shinjw `/etc/openvpn` was created.  I have not deleted it or its contents yet.  Also, `/etc/sysctl.conf` received a minor edit to enable ip forwarding. In addition, some commands were run, as shown in the tutorial in the link in my OP above.

Comment: try your `jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/atest?autoReconnect=true`

Comment: @shinjw I just now deleted `/etc/openvpn`, which was created in the tutorial. I also commented out the minor chance in `/etc/sysctl.conf` that was made in the tutorial. The only things I do not know how to undo are some of the commands that were run, such as `./clean-all`.  If those commands were limited to `/etc/openvpn` contents, then I erased their consequences, but I cannot be sure.  Also, it is not clear that the tutorial caused the problem.  I am just not sure what else to check because i did not make any other changes.

Comment: @shinjw Is there a way I can try `jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/atest?autoReconnect=true` from the terminal without having to redeploy a war with only that minor change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70818/discussion-between-shinjw-and-codemed).